# Git Bash - " 'node' " is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, git-bash

Hi I have problem with that but I can solve with this video [SOLVE VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeXB1SPQjUM&t=336s)

to solve my problem thanks

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. [Please post text, not links to videos of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) That's a seven-minute video...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.